# Kinect Fusion Raycast

Tags: graphics, kinect, point-clouds, raycasting

KinectFusion uses raycasting to determine the shading of each image point regarding the depth information provided by the kinect.

Can you actually use the raycasting functionality of KinectFusion or is it rather something internal and not exposed. I might have missed something in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

check this repo.
This has raycasting functionality in it.
https://github.com/Nerei/kinfu_remake

Comment: I have built my own raycaster and integrated it with the KinectFusion :) Thanks for the reply